# Error 'IO Error: Broken Pipe' when upgrading server from Debian Squeeze to Wheezy

Tags: debian, upgrade

As I am upgrading my virtual machine from Debian 6 (Squeeze) to 7 (Wheezy), I am seeing what appears to be a changelog (screenshot below).

So, I pressed the 'q' key to quit and proceed with the upgrade process, and I notice some error-like message (screenshot below).

**Changelog Screenshot:**

[image: Changelog Screenshot]

**Error Screenshot:**

[image: Error Screenshot]

**Relevant Error Text:**

```
...

Get:368 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main nmap amd64 6.00-0.3 [3,718 kB]
Fetched 166 MB in 23s (7,112 kB/s)
Reading changelogs... Done
apt-listchanges: Mailing root: apt-listchanges: news for li499-58
sh: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 237, in <module>
        main()
    File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 221, in main
        apt_listchanges.mail_changes(config.email_address, news, subject)
    File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/apt_listchanges.py", line 99, in mail_changes
        fh.write(message.as_string())
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Extracting templates from packages: 100%

...
```

Any idea what it is? Should this be a concern?

Comment: you can see this error when your ssh connection failed. possible to put a bigger screenshot?
Of course, upgrade from stable to testig or sid is very easy. don't worry. please give information. i can't see your screenshot.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh please open the screenshot images in a new tab/window. They are 1920x1080 px in resolution. :)

Comment: Please copy-paste the relevant text instead of posting screenshots. Screenshots aren't searchable.

Comment: @Gilles Updated the question. Please see if that's what you wanted me to do.

Comment: Yes, that's fine now. Thank you for being responsive even after you'd had your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because that Python program is trying to pipe to `/usr/sbin/sendmail`, which doesn't exist on your system.

This is nothing to worry about, all that happened was that `apt-listchanges` failed to send a mail to root about the changes made. The changes still happened, regardless.

If you don't want this to happen in future, either remove `apt-listchanges` if you don't need it, or install `sendmail`.

Comment: Instead of `sendmail`, I recommend any other [MTA](http://wiki.debian.org/MTA) (`postfix`, `exim`, ...). They are much nicer to configure and should all provide the /usr/sbin/sendmail binary.